# How to create a partially visible or half page activity on Android, similar to Share activity dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

How to create a partially visible or half page activity on Android, similar to Share activity dialog (for ex : that appears with `Intent.ACTION_SEND` )

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of this is done in the [ResolverActivity](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/app/ResolverActivity.java).
A [theme](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/app/ResolverActivity.java#207) is set such that the activity background becomes dim and translucent. The theme is [`Theme.DeviceDefault.Resolver`](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/themes_device_defaults.xml#544). The [`ResolverDrawerLayout`](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/ResolverDrawerLayout.java) contains the implementation of drag to expand behavior. The [BottomSheet](https://github.com/tutti-ch/android-bottomsheet) is based on the above source files and this android library is available from maven repo.